# How to pass plug loaded data to LiveView components

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

Hi I'm using different domain names to load different data sets. I'm currently using a custom plug to load the correct domain id based on the hostname. E.g. got this in my `endpoint.ex` just before the router:

```
plug WebApp.DomainCheck
socket "/live", Phoenix.LiveView.Socket, websocket: [connect_info: [session: @session_options]]
...
plug WebApp.Router
```

And

```
defmodule WebApp.DomainCheck do
  import Plug.Conn
  @behaviour Plug

  def init([]), do: []

  def call(conn, _options \\ []) do
    domains = Model.load_allowed_domains()
    case Map.get(domains, conn.host) do
      nil ->
        conn
        |> resp(401, "Domain not allowed")
        |> halt()

      domain_id ->
        conn
        |> assign(:domain_id, domain_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Now this works for normal `View` as I have the `domain_id` assign in each of them. But how do I get the `domain` data injected into my `LiveView`s as well from a plug?

Currently I've code duplicated the same domain check into **every LiveViews mount()** page:

```
defmodule WebApp.WelcomeLive do
  use WebApp, :live_view

  @impl true
  def mount(_args, _session, socket) do
    domains = Model.load_allowed_domains()
    host = socket.host_uri.host
    case Map.get(domains, host) do
      nil -> {:error, "Domain not allowed"}
      domain_id -> {:ok, assign(socket, :domain_id, domain_id)}
    end
  end
```

Is there any way I can make a plug effective in pushing this data down to the live views without need to add code to each mount?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar use case in my app where my plug puts the a `user` struct on  the `assigns` and I wanted to keep that data inside live view without reloading all stuff.

The only way I could achieve that was using the [option](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.Router.html#live/4) `session` from the `live` route passing it a MFA.

In the router you will have something like

```
live "/page", WebApp.SomeLiveView, :show, session: {WebAppp.Helpers, :keep_domain_id, []}
```

and your `WebApp.Helpers` will have that function returning what you want to be passed to your live view as `session`.

```
defmodule WebApp.Helpers do
  def keep_domain_id(conn) do
    %{"domain_id" => conn.assigns.domain_id}
  end
end
```

Then in your `mount` on you will have `"domain_id"` key in your `session`

```
defmodule WebApp.WelcomeLive do
  use WebApp, :live_view

  @impl true
  def mount(_args, %{"domain_id" => domain} = _session, socket) do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I think this works great for a user object, but isn't this session shared between all views? E.g. if a user has two open tabs on different host urls wouldn't the session values override each other?

Comment: Though they share the standard session from the client, some values will be the same indeed, but as you are getting `domain_id` value from the connection (in this case, from each tab), it will put the correct value in the session to that specific live view.

Comment: I'll try that and mark as the right answer if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately the `session` argument [was removed in LiveView 0.16.0 (2021-08-10)](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0160-2021-08-10). One should [define `on_mount` hook](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view/blob/42632f5535c66a664c9dcfcc4530690011fbec8e/guides/server/security-model.md#mounting-considerations) and mount that to any relevant LiveView(s).