# elixir phoenix liveview - passing user id through socket

Tags: elixir, phoenix-live-view

In `liveview`, how can I pass the user data from `leex` to the `context`?
I have `phx.gen.live` a `profiles` context, and I want to add user_id to the profile every time user create the new profile.
I change the create_profile code to:

```
**profiles.ex (context)**
  def create_profile(attrs \\ %{}, userid) do
    attrs = Map.put(attrs, "user_id", userid)
    %Profile{}
    |> Profile.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end
```

I am using `pow`, so in normal phoenix case, I would just do this:

```
user = Pow.Plug.current_user(conn) #<-- this is conn
Profiles.create_profile(profile_params, user.id)
```

but in `liveview`, instead of `conn`, it use `socket`. So I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: you can create a plug and pass the user_id through session

Comment: IDK if it answers your question but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357773/how-to-pass-plug-loaded-data-to-liveview-components/65359208#65359208
And if you are using standalone components inside any of your controllers you can pass it as session as well https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.Helpers.html#live_render/3

Comment: Thanks for the info. After spending the whole day staring at the code, I finally understand how it works. Anyway, I will read the link when I have time later.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of different ways to do this but I will describe a straightforward approach.

1. In the function where you "log in" a user, I assume you have access to the `conn`. I also assume you have a `user_token`, if you are using Pow. If so, do this:

```
conn
|> put_session(:user_token, user_token)
```

2. Now go to your `live_helpers.ex` file (or create it if you don't have one) and make a function like this:

```
  def assign_defaults(session, socket) do
    socket =
      socket
      |> assign_new(:current_user, fn ->
        find_current_user(session)
      end)

    socket
  end
```

3. Also, in `live_helpers`, write this function:

```
  defp find_current_user(session) do
    with user_token when not is_nil(user_token) <- session["user_token"],
         %User{} = user <- Accounts.get_user_by_session_token(user_token),
         do: user
  end
```

4. Now in any LiveView modules where you need to access the current_user, just put this in your `mount` function:

```
  def mount(_params, session, socket) do
    socket =
      assign_defaults(session, socket)

    {:ok, socket}
  end
```

And then you will have access to the `session.assigns.current_user`.

UPDATE: since I wrote my answer, a new function now exists that is well-suited for such "default assigns": https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#on_mount/1

These days, I will make a module called DefaultAssigns and use this function.  It's a small difference but it's certainly neater.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple pattern pulled from https://github.com/fly-apps/live_beats. It has the following steps:

1. Add `current_user` to socket assigns.
2. Use the `on_mount` in the live views where you want it.
3. Access `current_user` in the template.

#### Add `current_user` to socket assigns in `on_mount`

(see [lib/live_beats_web/controllers/user_auth.ex](https://github.com/fly-apps/live_beats/blob/95c69a4aa544f48046f2a4d82a6c19807617cc2b/lib/live_beats_web/controllers/user_auth.ex)):

```
defmodule LiveBeatsWeb.UserAuth do
  import Plug.Conn
  import Phoenix.Controller

  alias Phoenix.LiveView
  alias LiveBeats.Accounts
  alias LiveBeatsWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes

  def on_mount(:current_user, _params, session, socket) do
    case session do
      # I think you have to manually add `user_id` to session. I used
`user_token` instead of `user_id` (because it's already in session due to the `fetch_current_user` plug in the browser pipeline) and `Accounts.get_user_by_session_token(user_token)` instead of `Accounts.get_user(user_id)`
      %{"user_id" => user_id} ->
        {:cont, LiveView.assign_new(socket, :current_user, fn -> Accounts.get_user(user_id) end)}

      %{} ->
        {:cont, LiveView.assign(socket, :current_user, nil)}
    end
  end

...
end
```

#### Use the `on_mount` in the live views where you want it.

(see [lib/live_beats_web/live/player_live.ex](https://github.com/fly-apps/live_beats/blob/95c69a4aa544f48046f2a4d82a6c19807617cc2b/lib/live_beats_web/live/player_live.ex)):

```
defmodule LiveBeatsWeb.PlayerLive do
  use LiveBeatsWeb, {:live_view, container: {:div, []}}

  alias LiveBeats.{Accounts, MediaLibrary}
  alias LiveBeats.MediaLibrary.Song

  # this uses the `on_mount` defined above. `:current_user` matches the first argument of `on_mount` above. It can say whatever you want, but it has to match in both places.
  on_mount {LiveBeatsWeb.UserAuth, :current_user}
  
  ...

  def mount(_parmas, _session, socket) do
    %{current_user: current_user} = socket.assigns

    if connected?(socket) do
      Accounts.subscribe(current_user.id)
    end

    socket =
      socket
      |> assign(
        song: nil,
        playing: false,
        profile: nil,
        current_user_id: current_user.id,
        own_profile?: false
      )
      |> switch_profile(current_user.active_profile_user_id || current_user.id)

    {:ok, socket, layout: false, temporary_assigns: []}
  end
```

#### Access `current_user` in the template

(I didn't find an example of this in that repo, but here's how you get properties of current_user)

```
User id: <%= @current_user.id %>
```

Comment: Here is a longer article with other similar patterns you can use: https://blog.appsignal.com/2022/01/25/securing-your-phoenix-liveview-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Declares a module callback to be invoked on the LiveView's mount at router.

```
live_session :authenticated, on_mount: {AppWeb.InitAssigns, :current_user} do
    scope "/", AppWeb do
      pipe_through([:browser, :require_authenticated_user])

      live("/users/dashboardb", DashboardLive.Index, :index)
end
end
```

2. Create InitAssigns:

```
defmodule AppWeb.InitAssigns do
  @moduledoc """
  Ensures common `assigns` are applied to all LiveViews attaching this hook.
  """
  import Phoenix.LiveView
  import Phoenix.Component

  alias App.Accounts
  alias App.Accounts.User

  def on_mount(:current_user, params, session, socket) do
    IO.inspect(params, label: "+++++++++++++++=========================I WAS HIT")
    # code
    socket =
      socket
      |> assign_new(:current_user, fn ->
        find_current_user(session)
      end)

    if socket.assigns.current_user do
      {:cont, socket}
    else
      {:halt, redirect(socket, to: "/")}
    end
  end

  defp find_current_user(session) do
    with user_token when not is_nil(user_token) <- session["user_token"],
         %User{} = user <- Accounts.get_user_by_session_token(user_token),
         do: user
  end
end
```

3. Done